# Java ConcurrentModificationException only in deployed environment

Tags: java

I have a contractor-developed Java application to support - my experience is mostly with .NET and I don't have access to anyone with knowledge of the application code.  This application works fine in my development environment when running on the Tomcat server within Eclipse.  However, after deploying the WAR to a remote server (still in the development environment), I get a Concurrent Modification Exception.  I'd like to see what possible causes there could be before I jump in and review all the application code line-by-line.

My understanding is this exception is usually triggered by modifying an iterator object while you're in the process of iterating through it.  But then why did I not get the exception when running in Eclipse?  If this is for sure a bug within the code, how do I find where it is in the code if Eclipse isn't triggering the exception?  The exception trace is vague to me (pasted below).  The only file reference I see is to a view template and .  If I have to rely on the deployed application to debug, how do I find out where in the code this bug is?    Is it possible this is an environment issue - and if so, what could be causing it?

```
Sep 6, 2016 3:50:57 PM com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy handleRenderException
SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/views/editor.xhtml]
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.nextEntry(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$EntryIterator.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$EntryIterator.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.AbstractMap.equals(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedMap.equals(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.context.SessionMap.put(SessionMap.java:138)
    at com.sun.faces.context.SessionMap.put(SessionMap.java:61)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ServerSideStateHelper.writeState(ServerSideStateHelper.java:243)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ResponseStateManagerImpl.writeState(ResponseStateManagerImpl.java:122)
    at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.writeState(StateManagerImpl.java:113)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.WriteBehindStateWriter.flushToWriter(WriteBehindStateWriter.java:225)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:464)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:286)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1770)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.nextEntry(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$EntryIterator.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$EntryIterator.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.AbstractMap.equals(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedMap.equals(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.context.SessionMap.put(SessionMap.java:138)
    at com.sun.faces.context.SessionMap.put(SessionMap.java:61)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ServerSideStateHelper.writeState(ServerSideStateHelper.java:243)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ResponseStateManagerImpl.writeState(ResponseStateManagerImpl.java:122)
    at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.writeState(StateManagerImpl.java:113)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.WriteBehindStateWriter.flushToWriter(WriteBehindStateWriter.java:225)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:464)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:286)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1770)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Does this occur in any code that you own?  That is to say, is the cause of this stack trace from an internal source or from an external library?

Comment: The exception is thrown if you modify the *iterated* object outside the iterator, not modifying the `iterator` itself. One possibility is modification from another thread, another - in the iteration loop there's something that mutates the map. You likely don't get the exception in your local build because there aren't multiple concurrent sessions. However, the first thing you should do is find out *where* the problem is. I can't find any custom package in your stack trace.

Comment: @Makoto Honestly, I don't know how to tell...

Comment: @Ordous Would the remote Tomcat start multiple concurrent sessions even if I'm the only user?  Is that a Tomcat-level thing, or an application-level thing?Both the Eclipse Tomcat and remote Tomcat versions of this application were accessed through an iframe inside a completely separate application (so they were both accessed the same way), and I was the only user.

Comment: @matikin9 Easiest way to force 2 or more sessions on a local machine is to log on in two different browsers (that don't share information). Like chrome and FF. What you have to do then is anyone's guess. Hence why I said it would be best to find a place in *your* code where it breaks - then you can simply put the server into remote debug mode and put a breakpoint there (and step through the live code on the server as the bug unfolds, rather than try to reproduce it locally).

Answer (score 1):

Since the stacktrace only shows internal APIs (Tomcat, JSF, JDK) it's hard to draw any conclusions. As we know, `ConcurrentModificationException` happens when we're iterating a `fail-fast` collection and it's modified during iteration. This can happen from a different thread, but just as easily from the same thread. If you're not sure how that works, SO is full of examples.

If we assume that the modification is happening in the same thread, then the stacktrace would show the culprits. In this case it would be somewhere around [com.sun.faces.context.SessionMap.put(SessionMap.java:138)](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.faces/jsf-impl/2.2.1/com/sun/faces/context/SessionMap.java#138).

Based on the code (`doSet = ! result.equals(value);`) and the stacktrace, it's checking the equality of a `LinkedHashMap` to `value`, which we can see from the stacktrace is also a `LinkedHashMap`.

However we can also see that `result` is wrapped with `Collections.synchronizedMap()`. This is significant because as we know those wrappers make the collections thread-safe for simple operations (like `get()/put()`) but require [manual synchronization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap-java.util.Map-) for iteration. It also means that all access needs to go through the synchronized wrapper to keep it safe.

If this isn't a JSF bug, we can assume that there's another thread that has access to that map, and it isn't behaving nicely. However if this is a multithreading issue, it's somewhat bizarre that the error should show up so consistently.

I'd need more access to the system to give any more insight (this is not a request for more access).

EDIT:
If it wasn't clear, the problem is happening because a `LinkedHashMap` is being put into the session and there's already a value for that key. When they're being compared if they're equal, the map being put in the session is modified and a `ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown.

Comment: That gives me an idea - I can update the exception catching to give me more info on where this is happening.  It's just annoying cause I have to re-deploy every change before I can test it.

Answer (score 1):

Servlets are reused and therefore need to be threadsafe.

My guess is that your code uses a `LinkedHashMap` that is either a static field or an instance field of your servlet and which is modified during web calls.

Your dev environment is obviously not being tested with concurrent calls, so doesn't encounter concurrency problems.

The simplest fix is to change the map implementation to the threadsafe [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html), or reorganise the code to use a copy of the map or otherwise avoid concurrent access while it is being modified.

Comment: I've seen a few HashMaps in the code, but it's kind of a mess to step through.  Looks like I'll just have to slog through it.  :'(  Also, I don't see how the remote Tomcat is getting concurrent calls when I'm the only user.

Comment: I think a big clue in the stacktrace is `java.util.AbstractMap.equals`. Look for code that compares maps using `.equals()` or implicitly calls this eg if adding/finding a map in a Set or as a Map key. You can also put your server in debug mode m, connect your IDE to it and set a breakpoint in `LinkedHashMap$LinkHashIterator.nextEntry()` where it throws the exception, then inspect the debug info for clues.

Answer (score -3):

Well this is a long shot, but remember that you only have one instance of your servlet Class serving all requests. So if you servlet class have any fields with iterators this might happen because 2 threads try to use the same iterator.

If that is not it: Try to get a copy of the entire tomcat server running on the remote server. You should be able to just get it as tar file, and then extract it and run it on your computer. This issue might be due to different tomcat versions or tomcat configurations.